# Stacking ViewPagers and dispatching touch events

Tags: android, android-viewpager, touch-event

I have a very strange requirement from a client as follows:

Create a view that does the following:
- User should be able to swipe up and down to switch between various clock face views.
- User should be able to swipe left and right to switch between various background images.

My first thought was to have a class that extends FrameLayout, add a [VerticalViewPager](https://github.com/castorflex/VerticalViewPager/blob/master/library/src/main/java/fr/castorflex/android/verticalviewpager/VerticalViewPager.java), add another ViewPager on top of it, set the appropriate adapters with their content, and then override the FrameLayout's `onTouchEvent` and `onInterceptTouchEvent` methods as follows

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    switch (ev.getActionMasked()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            // store the X value when the user's finger was pressed down
            downXValue = ev.getX();
            downYValue = ev.getY();
            break;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

float downXValue, downYValue;
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    Log.e(TAG, event.toString());
    float currentX = event.getX();
    float currentY = event.getY();

    if (Math.abs(downXValue - currentX) > Math.abs(downYValue
            - currentY)) {
        mHorizPager.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    } else {
        mVerticalPager.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    }
    return true;
}
```

While this technically *works* in that it correctly dispatches the MotionEvent to the appropriate ViewPager, swiping the horizontal view is extremely stuttery and only rarely actually changes the current ViewPager item.

My suspicion is that my implementation of `onInterceptTouchEvent` and `onTouchEvent` are a little too naive for what it needs to do, but I'm honestly at my wits end attempting to debug this.